# Mongoid edit form in Ruby not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a simple application that has a hotline model which is a mongoid document.  The create and view works fine but the edit I cant seem to get to work for the life of me.

I was hoping someone could help me identify what I am doing wrong.

This is my create form which works properly:

```
  <%= form_for Hotline.new, :url => {:action => "create"} do |f| %>
    <div class="row top-buffer">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-1 rt-label" for="textinput">Address</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <%= f.text_field :city, class: 'form-control input-sm', placeholder: "City" %>
        </div>
        <label class="col-sm-1" for="textinput"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <%= f.text_field :zip, class: 'form-control input-sm', placeholder: "Zip" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-1" for="textinput"></label>
      <%= f.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-sm btn-success' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

I tried changing the url to post or create and using the h in my edit form... but it keeps giving me no route matches errors.

```
No route matches {:action=>"patch", :controller=>"hotlines", :person_id=>"2"}
```

Here is the form with the view and put or patch as the action:

```
<% @hotlines.each do |h| %>
  <div id="log" class="visable">
    <p>View Log</p>
    <%= "City: " + h.city %><br>
    <%= "Zip: " + h.zip %><br>
  </div>
  <br>
    <div id="edit" class="visable">
      <p>Edit Log</p>


  <%= form_for h, :url => {:action => "patch"} do |f| %>
    <div class="row top-buffer">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-1 rt-label" for="textinput">Address</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <%= f.text_field :city, class: 'form-control input-sm', placeholder: "City" %>
        </div>
        <label class="col-sm-1" for="textinput"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <%= f.text_field :zip, class: 'form-control input-sm', placeholder: "Zip" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-1" for="textinput"></label>
      <%= f.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-sm btn-success' %>
    </div>
  <% end %> 


  </div>


  <% end %>
```

Not sure if this is need but here are a few more bits from my code.

Controller (I realize the update is incomplete but I cant seem to get it even render edit)

```
class HotlinesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @person = Person.find(params['person_id'])
    #binding.pry
    #@person = Person.find(params: id)
    #@hotlines = Hotline.where(person_id: @person.id)
    @hotlines = Hotline.where(person_id: params['person_id'])
  end

  def new
    @new_hotline = Hotline.new
  end  

  def create
    @new_hotline = Hotline.new(hotline_params)
    @new_hotline.person_id = params['person_id']
    if @new_hotline.save
      redirect_to person_hotlines_path(params['person_id']), notice: "Hotline was added successfully."
    else
      flash[:error] = "Error creating hotline. Please try again."
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    @person = Person.find(params['person_id'])
    @update_hotline = Hotline.find(params[:id])
     if @update_hotline.update_attributes(person_params)
       redirect_to person_hotlines_path(params['person_id']), notice: "Person was updated successfully."
     else
       flash[:error] = "Error saving person. Please try again."
       render :edit
     end  
  end

  private

  def hotline_params
    params.require(:hotline).permit(:person_id, :city, :zip)
  end    
end
```

Routes

```
  devise_for :users
  resources :users, only: [:update, :index, :new, :edit, :create] 
  resources :dashboard, only: [:index]
  resources :people do
    resources :hotlines, only: [:index, :create, :update, :new]
  end

  post 'dashboard/search'
  get '/person/:id', to: 'person#show'
  get 'welcome/index'
  get 'welcome/about'

  root to: 'welcome#index'
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your update url is related to the fact that there is no action and route with name "patch". Please update it to:

```
<%= form_for h, :url => {:action => "update", :method => :put } do |f| %>
```

Or use named routes. This console command will help you with available routes:

```
"rake routes | grep user"
```

And then edit form become:

```
<%= form_for h, :url => user_path(h) do |f| %>
```

For more information visit: 
    http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Hope it does help.

Comment: Thanks Marcin, but using the 

'<%= form_for h, :url => {:action => "update", :method => :put } do |f| %>'

I get 

'No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"hotlines", :method=>:put, :person_id=>"2"}'

Using rake routes I do see

    person_hotline PATCH  /people/:person_id/hotlines/:id(.:format) hotlines#update
                     PUT    /people/:person_id/hotlines/:id(.:format) hotlines#update'

Comment: You are trying to create url for nested resources. Named routes would be better that hash with :action/:method try: `code`(person_hotline_path(person, hotline). More info and examples [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)